# Sorting values in multiple lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

Currently, I have a list of lists called `result` which will contain values like this, for example:

```
result[1] = [John,  0.32]
result[2] = [Mikey, 1.90]
result[3] = [Sarah, 1.31]
result[4] = [Nancy, 0.49]
result[5] = [Billy, 0.13]
```

I want to however, sort this in descending order by the number which is held in the index space [1]. So the system will return the values in that order. Would I just have to use the `sorted()` function and call up the index where the value is held? I do not need to resort the list is it is necessary, i will just need to output the values in descending order.

How would I go about doing this exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `key` parameter in the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

```
sorted(result, key = lambda x:x[1], reverse = True)
```

The `reverse = True` makes sure that the items are sorted in the descending order. The important thing to be noted here is the `key` parameter.

```
key = lambda x:x[1]
```

We pass a lambda function to the `key` parameter, which accepts one parameter. `sorted` picks each element from `result` and pass that to the `key` function. In our case it is the tuples. The `key` function returns the second item in the tuples. So, the second item in the tuple will be used as the value of the tuple itself, while sorting. It means that when we comapre `[John,  0.32]` and `[Mikey, 1.90]`, we will be actually comparing `0.32` and `1.90` only.

`sorted` doesn't change the actual list, but creates a new sorted list. But, if you want to sort the list itself, then you can use `list.sort` method, like this

```
result.sort(key = lambda x:x[1], reverse = True)
```

Comment: so the list will just be sorted here or will i need to declare a new list and make it equal to the function?

Comment: @user3502748 Please check the last line in the answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `sorted`:

```
new_list = sorted(old_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

or using `sort`:

```
old_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```